# Yii2 URL Management - issue in passing key-value pairs in URL

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

I am upgrading my website from Yii 1.1 to Yii2. In the older site using Yii 1.1, the url can be given as

`http://example.com/index.php/controller_name/action_name/queryString/123`

But in Yii2 I have to change this request to

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller_name/action_name?queryString=123
```

in order to make it work, otherwise I get a **404 Not Found** error.

I already know that this feature has been removed in Yii2 [Github issue 6866](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6866), but since the older site heavily uses this particular feature, I would like to know if there is any workaround, without changing each individual URL in the existing website.

Thanks

Comment: You need to create your own rules for this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-rules and add them to application bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable pretty urls,and the add rules accordingly.